# Python - Pushing values present in a array to Dictionary

Tags: python

I need to reconstruct a new dictionary based on the keys present in an array.from an existing dictionary. array value will be changing each and every time

```
olddict =   {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964,
  "createdby": "Mustang",
  "orderedby": "Mustang"
}

arr = ['brand','year','createdby']
```

Required output :

```
newdict=    {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "year": 1964,
  "createdby": "Mustang"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
newdict = {param:olddict.get(param) for param in arr}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Dictionary Comprehension** technique.

```
newdict = {key:olddict[key] for key in arr}
```

where `key` is everything in `arr` list/array and value of `newdict` is `olddict[key]`.

Hope you find it easy and useful <3

Answer (score 0):

```
olddict =   {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964,
  "createdby": "Mustang",
  "orderedby": "Mustang"
}

arr = ['brand','year','createdby']

newdict = {}

for key in arr:
    # key = 'brand'
    newdict[key] = olddict[key]    # newdict['brand'] = olddict['brand']

newdict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "year": 1964,
  "createdby": "Mustang"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function:

```
def updated_dict(arr, olddict):
    newdict = {}
    for item in arr:
        newdict[item] = olddict.get(item)

    return newdict
```